# How do I solve this rspec-support version error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rubygems, simplecov

When I try running the rspec file of a task of my ruby application by using the command

> rspec /Users/priyanshu.sahoo/Desktop/Fk/ltl-worker/spec/tasks/four_kites_common/background_job/tasks/calculate_auto_delivery_appointment_time_task_spec.rb

I get this error.

> An error occurred while loading spec_helper. - Did you mean?
> rspec ./spec/spec_helper.rb Failure/Error: require 'simplecov' LoadError:   cannot load such file -- simplecov
> #./spec/spec_helper.rb:1:in `<top (required)>' No examples found.

This is my first time working with a rails application. Can anyone help me resolve this?
I am using ruby 2.7.5p203, rails 4.2.11.1

Comment: ¿have you installed the gems with `bundle install`? it looks like you're missing simplecov gem, you might try installing it in case isn't in your `Gemfile` or add it there.

Comment: group :test do
  gem 'simplecov', '~> 0.12.0'
end

Comment: Adding this in the gemfile did the job